# Elastic Search indexing for many different mapping types

Tags: elasticsearch

I have implemented something like Class and Instance logic in my application where I create an object named category which is a blue print for it's instances.
User has freedom to create as many Categories as they like with whatever fields hence I used to use one new TYPE for each category in my elastic search index mapping until it was deprecated in latest upgrades.
With latest upgrades of ES , I can think of only these 2 approaches -

- creating one index for each category
- keeping one object type field named after the TYPE that holds fields for

each category and keep updating this one mapping every time.

I am trying to decide on which approach to take up for ES upgrade to version 7 from 5 to keep this dynamic nature of my data modelling. Searches would be governed by TYPE string that is system generated ID for each category hence need to have grouping of fields based on the category they belong to.

**OLD MAPPINGS - NOW DEPRECATED**

first one - one for each TYPE(category)

```json
{
  "type_cat1" : {
    "dynamic" : "strict"
      "mapping" :{
        "field11" : {...}
      }
   }
}
```

second one and so on

```json
{
  "type_cat2" : {
    "dynamic" : "strict"
      "mapping" :{
        "field21" : {...}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**NEW MAPPING WITH OBJECTS FOR EACH OLD TYPE**

```json
{
    "mapping" :{
        "properties" :{
            "type_cat1" : {
                "properties" :{
                    "field11" : {...}
                }
            },
        
        "type_cat2" : {
                "properties" :{
                    "field11" : {...}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ALTERNATIVE NEW MAPPING - ONE INDEX PER CATEGORY (not more than 500)**

One index would be created separately for each category...

Please advice if a better approach is out there or which one to choose among these...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar use-case at my workplace where the user can create an object with any number of fields, each field can be of any datatype.

Our approach is similar to one of yours:

- All categories will be mapped to a single index.
- Whenever a new object is created, the index mappings are updated to accommodate the new object (a category in your case).

This is what our mappings look like when molded to your needs:

```json
{
  "mappings": {
    "category": {     // this is a field present in all documents
        "type": "keyword"
    },
    "createdTime": {  // this is a field present in all documents
        "type": "date"
    },
    "id": {           // this is a field present in all documents
        "type": "long"
    },
    "fields": {
        "properties": {
            "type_cat1": {
                "properties": {
                    "field1": {...},
                    "field2": {...}
                }
            },
            "type_cat2": {
                "properties": {
                    "field1": {...},
                    "field2": {...}
                }
            },
            {...}
        }
    }
}
```

Get all records of a certain category:

```
"category": "cat1"
```

Get all records of *cat1* where field2 == "dummy_value"

```
"category": "cat1 AND "fields.cat1.field2.keyword": "dummy_value"
```

When a new category is created, the *fields* part of our mappings get updated.

Extracting out the common fields `(category, createdTime, id)` eliminates redundancy in mappings.

Some worthy points:

- As the number of unique categories is only 500, you can also go with a separate index per category. This is more beneficial if there are going to be many records (> 1,00,000) per category.
- If the categories are sparse in nature (each category has less number records), then ES can easily handle everything in a single index.
- If we assume 50 fields per category on average, then the total fields in the single index approach will be 50*500 = 25000. This is a manageable number.
- Of course, in the end, many things will depend upon resources allocated to the cluster.

Comment: Much appreciate the elaborate answer ,will you be able to provide with some credible references that I can go through for better understanding.